# drawing start and end time as intervall in one thick line

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to draw some highcharts graph where the time intervals is being displayed as a thick line  based on the date  in one line so my series data are start and end times (Timestamp Objects from the database).

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
                                spacingTop: 0,
                                paddingTop: 0,
                                zoomType: 'x'
                        },
    title: {
        text: 'Workink time'
    },
    yAxis: {
            title: {
            text: 'Driving time'
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
                        type: 'datetime',
                     },      
    series: [{
        name: 'Date',

        data: [
            [Date.UTC(1970, 9, 21), 0],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 4), 0.28],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 9), 0.25],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 27), 0.2],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 2), 0.28],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 26), 0.28],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 29), 0.47],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 11), 0.79],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 26), 0.72],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 1, 3), 1.02],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 1, 11), 1.12],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 1, 25), 1.2],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 2, 11), 1.18],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 3, 11), 1.19],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 1), 1.85],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 5), 2.22],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 19), 1.15],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 5, 3), 0]
        ]
    }]
});
```

It could be look like this picture.

[image]

Comment: So, is there a question? What have you tried to do? What isn't working? What do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a serie for each of your start and end date tuple, link all of them the first series by setting an id for the first serie

```
id: 'Installation'
```

and using

```
linkedTo: 'Installation',
```

and set the same color

```
var color = '#7cb5ec';
```

this is how the series should look like

```
series: [{
    id: 'Installation',
    name: 'Installation',
    color: color,
    data: [[Date.UTC(1970, 9, 21), 1], [Date.UTC(1970, 9, 22), 1]]
}, {
    name: 'Manufacturing',
    linkedTo: 'Installation',
    color: color,
    data: [[Date.UTC(1970, 9, 23), 1], [Date.UTC(1970, 9, 24), 1]]
}, {
    name: 'Sales & Distribution',
    linkedTo: 'Installation',
    color: color,
    data: [[Date.UTC(1970, 9, 25), 1], [Date.UTC(1970, 9, 30), 1]]
}, {
    name: 'Project Development',
    linkedTo: 'Installation',
    color: color,
    data: [[Date.UTC(1970, 10, 5), 1], [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 10), 1]]
}, {
    name: 'Other',
    linkedTo: 'Installation',
    color: color,
    data: [[Date.UTC(1970, 10, 12), 1], [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 30), 1]]
}]
```

here if the full fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/32mhbyc5/

Comment: Introducing multiple series seems to over-complicate this quite a bit

Comment: You can make a loop to create the series, this is the only thing i could come up with

Comment: Well, again, since the post doesn't ask an actual question, it's hard to answer. The data points in the original code don't seem to lend themselves to the chart type illustrated without further explanation. But either way, there's no need for multiple series to accomplish a broken line.

Answer (score 0):

As I am unsure what the data in your example is meant to represent, I have used the data as @Liviu Boboia parsed it, to provide another example of how to create the broken line visual using the `columnrange` series type.

Code:

```
series: [{
  data: [
    [1, Date.UTC(1970, 9, 21), Date.UTC(1970, 9, 22)],
    [1, Date.UTC(1970, 9, 23), Date.UTC(1970, 9, 24)],
    [1, Date.UTC(1970, 9, 25), Date.UTC(1970, 9, 30)],
    [1, Date.UTC(1970, 10, 5), Date.UTC(1970, 10, 10)],
    [1, Date.UTC(1970, 10, 12), Date.UTC(1970, 10, 30)]
  ]
}]
```

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/0jme6at3/

Output:

[image]